# Get product stock quantity in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, products, stock

I need to get product stock quantity for the item, how to get that

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'weight' ,'price','description'));

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $p['products'][] = array(
        'id'        => $product->getId(),
        'sku'       => $product->getSku(),
        'name'      => $product->getName(),
        'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
        'weight'      => $product->getWeight(),
        'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
        'pirce'     => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,
    );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to join the table to get qty.

See below code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'weight' ,'price','description'))
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $p['products'][] = array(
        'id'            => $product->getId(),
        'sku'           => $product->getSku(),
        'name'          => $product->getName(),
        'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
        'weight'        => $product->getWeight(),
        'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
        'pirce'         => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,
        //get qty
        'qty'           => $product->getQty(),
    );
}
```

> How to get created attribute value here for eg i have created a attribute named size how to fetch that value

**UPDATE (Although you should ask in another qst, but I will answer here for you.)**

To get custom attribute you will need to add attribute in `->addAttributeToSelect` section.

[**Still doesn't work?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959415/get-custom-attribute-from-product-in-magento-1-9#answer-27959431)

You might need to load a product model as sometimes I've experienced that not all custom attributes are attached when you pull it out of a collection (intended for performance reasons I guess). Something like:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$size = $_product->getSize();
```

Comment: how to get created attribute value here for eg i have created a attribute named size how to fetch that value

Comment: Try `$product->getSize()` or `$product->getData('size')`

Comment: Its returning null values only

Comment: Have you added your custom attribute in `->addAttributeToSelect`? You have to tell what to select. otherwise just use `->addAttributeToSelect(*)` instead. This will select everything related to product. If this doesn't work then check my updated answer shortly.

Comment: Yes i have added

Comment: I ran into the same problem and I was able to get the stock information for each product within a product collection. Check the code below @vellaidurai. 
        `$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();      
        $products->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'description'));
      $products->joinTable('cataloginventory/stock_item','product_id=entity_id', array('qty'));
        
        foreach ($products as $product){
            // attributes here..
            $sku    = $product->getSku();
            $qty    = $product->getQty();
        }`

Answer (score 19):

It's working for me.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $_product) {
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
    echo $stock->getQty();
    echo $stock->getMinQty();
    echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding stock information to product collections can be done with a single line:

```
/* Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$products->setFlag('require_stock_items', true);
```

This flag is used in `catalog_product_collection_load_after` observer:

```
/**
 * Add information about producs stock status to collection
 * Used in for product collection after load
 *
 * @param   Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return  Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer
 */
public function addStockStatusToCollection($observer)
{
    $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
    if ($productCollection->hasFlag('require_stock_items')) {
        Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')->addItemsToProducts($productCollection);
    } else {
        Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_status')->addStockStatusToProducts($productCollection);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

If this flag is not set `$product->getStockItem()->getData()` has only `is_in_stock` set. With flag you can get qty, backorders, ... for every product in collection

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getStockItem()->getQty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can can access the products stock quantity via StockItem like this:

```
$_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

Tested in `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`