# How is the qty loaded from database?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, stock, inventory

Qty on the database tables **cataloginventory_stock** and **cataloginventory_stock_item** are different from Magento admin page.
I'm assuming there is a problem to load qty from the database.

I want to know how to load qty information from database to Magento admin page.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'weight' ,'price','description'))
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $p['products'][] = array(
        'id'            => $product->getId(),
        'sku'           => $product->getSku(),
        'name'          => $product->getName(),
        'description'   => $product->getDescription(),
        'weight'        => $product->getWeight(),
        'created at'    => $product->getCreatedAt(),
        'pirce'         => Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode,
        'qty'           => $product->getQty(),
    );
}
```

Check this link for more [Get product stock quantity in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106455/get-product-stock-quantity-in-magento)

Comment: can you tell me the path of this code?

Comment: Which admin page do you want to load?

Comment: on magento admin page....what do you mean which admin?

Comment: Sorry , this code can help you to get product stock. You can use it for your problem . This is snippet of code.

Comment: Which part of adming page , the qty is not right? Catalog grid? Admin Edit product ?

Comment: on the "cataloginventory_stock" and "cataloginventory_stock_itme" qty are correct, but on "catalog < manage product Grid" it shows me wrong qty

Comment: sku not get ''sku'   => $product->getSku(),'

Answer (score 2):

3 tables are mainly used to manage the stock : cataloginventory_stock, cataloginventory_stock_item and cataloginventory_stock_status

If you need to get or update a product's stock quantity you will need to find the relevant line in the cataloginventory_stock_item table
It's not normal that quantity show in Magento Admin page is different, do you use third party extension to manage stock like ERP ?